# Bizarre unexpected result in inheritance

Tags: c++

Very simple program. class B inherits A and I'm trying to print both the data members but the data member `a` of class A gets printed as a garbage value and not the actual value due to some reason.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

class A { 
    int a;
public:    
    A(int x) {
        x = a;
    }
    int getA() {
        return a;
    }
};

class B : private A {
    int b;
public:
    B(int x, int y) : A(y)  {
        b = x;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << getA() << endl << b << endl;
    }    
};

int main() {
    B b(10,20);
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1627414140
>
> 10

Comment: This wouldn't have happened if you'd used the constructor initialization list. And it has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Any particular reason you need private inheritance? Public is the norm.

Comment: @EMBLEM But private increases encapsulation, and could thus be considered better practice.

Answer (score 12):

Your error is here:

```
A(int x) {
    x = a;
}
```

I believe you want that to be:

```
A(int x) {
    a = x;
}
```